# Brownie empty traceback and revert_msg

Tags: brownie, console, trace

I'm trying to create a Yearn strategy following https://github.com/yearn/brownie-strategy-mix.

But a transaction is failing, and brownie isn't telling me why:

```py
% brownie console
Brownie environment is ready.

>>> vault = Vault.at("0xBFa4D8AA6d8a379aBFe7793399D3DdaCC5bBECBB")  # yvDAI (v0.2.2)
token = Token.at("0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f")  # DAI
gov = "ychad.eth"  # ENS for Yearn Governance Multisig
>>> strategy = Strategy.deploy(vault, {"from": accounts[0]})
Transaction sent: 0x7c60accb7ffcfe16f59f09ff6275edae75d31b981ef88ee3430bd8e0899a0b64
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 2
  Strategy.constructor confirmed   Block: 13382900   Gas used: 2539686 (21.16%)
  Strategy deployed at: 0xE7eD6747FaC5360f88a2EFC03E00d25789F69291

>>> tx = vault.addStrategy(strategy, 0.5, 1000, 2 ** 256 - 1, 50, {"from": gov})
Transaction sent: 0x94e787d2209c99a0501c6e2194b3c2429e916f1386156508bf2527fa63764364
  Gas price: 0.0 gwei   Gas limit: 12000000   Nonce: 1
  Vault.addStrategy confirmed (reverted)   Block: 13382901   Gas used: 24909 (0.21%)
```

when i try to inspect it, there's no traceback?

```py
>>> tx.traceback()

>>> tx.revert_msg
''
```

I have the vyper source for the Vault contract pulled in from https://github.com/yearn/yearn-vaults. Why can't I see it from brownie?